# Streaming multiple svg strings to png in nodejs using promises

Tags: node.js, svg, promise, stream, pdfmake

I am trying to convert multiple svg strings to png's so I can render them onto a pdf using PdfMake in nodejs. This works fine for one svg, but when I add multiple svg strings, they get overwritten by the last one. With this example code, it renders two images of png2 (svg2).

```
const promises = [svg1,svg2].map(str => {
    const stream = new Readable();
    stream.push(str);
    stream.push(null);
    return svgPromise(stream);
});

const result = await Promise.all(promises);

const png1 = result[0].content;
const png2 = result[1].content;

function svgPromise(stream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const svg = new Rsvg();
    stream.pipe(svg);
    svg.on("finish", function() {
      const buffer = svg.render({
          format: "png",
          width: width * 2,
          height: height * 2
      }).data;
      const png = datauri.format(".png", buffer);
      resolve(png);
    });
  });
}
```

Not sure if this error is related to stream or my promise logic. Any ideas?

Dependencies:

"librsvg": "0.7.0"
"pdfmake": "0.1.35"
"datauri": "1.0.5"

Comment: You didn't mention, is it [node-rsvg](https://github.com/walling/node-rsvg) you are using?

Comment: I'm using librsvg https://www.npmjs.com/package/librsvg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pays to list all the used modules. Assuming you used [datauri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datauri), it seems you need to initialize a new instance for every call:

```
      svg.on("finish", function() {
          const datauri = new Datauri();
          const buffer = svg.render({
              format: "png",
              width: 16,
              height: 16
          }).data;
          const png = datauri.format(".png", buffer);
          resolve(png);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you! Creating a new instance of datauri each time fixed it.

My apologies, I edited my answer with the used dependencies.